# The :id is there but i cant access it, how is this possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In the browser address bar i have `http://localhost:3000/comment/index?post_id=6`, i can access the post_id in the index,but when trying to create comment/post in the create action, it says couldnt find post without post ID in the log.What is going on here?thank you in advance.

Comments controller:

```
def index
  @post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
end

def create
  @post     = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment  = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.save

  respond_with( @comment, :layout => !request.xhr? )          
end
```

`comments/index` view:

```
<%= form_for :comment, :remote => true,
                       :url => { :controller => "comments",
                                 :action     => "create"
                               },
                       :html => { :id => 'new-comment'} do |f|
%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit "post" %>
<% end %>
```

In the log:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-17 14:06:36 -0700
  Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  
    "authenticity_token"=>"cxQm2K2xwsyw0DY2XLNvkcMQI+wM96LpEENbfQqxu5c=",
    "comment"=> {"post_id"=>"6", "body"=>"This is the comment"},
    "commit"=>"post"}
  Completed 404 Not Found in 23ms

  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post without an ID):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look in the params hash in your log, you'll see this:

```
{ "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"cxQm2K2xwsyw0DY2XLNvkcMQI+wM96LpEENbfQqxu5c=",
  "comment"=> {
      "post_id"=>"6", # <-- there's your post_id
      "body"=>"This is the comment" },
  "commit"=>"post" }
```

So the post ID is there, but it's inside the `comment` hash. So, in your create action, you just need to change to:

```
def create
  @post=Post.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.save
  respond_with( @comment, :layout => !request.xhr? )          
end
```

However, you should be able to simplify the create action a bit.

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.save
  respond_with( @comment, :layout => !request.xhr? )
end
```

Since the `post_id` is in the `comment` params, the comment will automatically be associated with the post when you create it, without having to look up the record. If you need to access the post in your view, you can use `@comment.post`.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not pass your field in as a `hidden_field` in the form. A better way to do this would be to go like this:

```
<%= form_for :comment,
             :remote => true,
             :url    => post_comments_path(post)
             :html => { :id => 'new-comment'} do |f| %>
```

By using the routing helpers that Rails provides you, this will clean up your form by:

1. Not having you use the ugly hash syntax to generate the URL for your form
2. Not have you place a `hidden_field` in the form to send through the URL; and
3. Automatically send through the post parameter as `params[:post_id]` just like <s>God</s> DHH intended.

This means you would be able to find it in your action with this line of code:

```
Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Rather than this, which is unnecessarily longer and therefore more painful to type:

```
Post.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
```